# speed up response of request with cache or binary response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

I want to speed up response of query with **cache** or **binary response**

It takes  more than **30 seconds ~ 500 seconds** to render a json response for 5k ~ 100k records.

How to make it more quickly ?

Because the response time is still slow on rendering

Is it possible to make a binary response (skip render view ) ?

```
  WeatherLog Load (335.5ms)  SELECT  "weather_logs".* FROM "weather_logs"   ORDER BY "weather_logs"."datetime" ASC LIMIT 90000
Write page /Users/public/index.json (35.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 40488ms (Views: 32459.3ms | ActiveRecord: 336.8ms)
```

### Controller

```
caches_page :index
respond_to :json

def index
  begin       
    @weather_logs = WeatherLog.result(q)

    respond_to do |format|
      render json: @weather_logs
      return
    end
  rescue Exception => e
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: {status: "Invalid Request #{e.backtrace.first(3)}"} }
    end
  end
end
```

### Dataflow : Step 4 is the bottleneck for rendering

[image]

### In short words

I only need to send the response to **client** in a short time,

No matter what format it is.

Even **binary** format is ok.

Please give me some direction or idea to boost the performance

Comment: Would streaming the response be an option for you? See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24292549/2463468

Comment: How big is the resulting file (or how big is a single entry)?

Comment: @mdrozdziel about dozens of thousand to million

Comment: Don't you mix the idea of caching result vs caching response?

Comment: "dozens of thousand to million" what's the unit?

Comment: What is the data size in megabytes?

Comment: @mdrozdziel the raw data size is about 500MB to 3 GB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it definitely just the rendering that is the problem, what is the result of WeatherLogs.result(q). Have you benchmarked the WeatherLogs#results call? How long does it take to iterate over that collection returned opposed to just rendering it? Are there any methods being called when rendering it to JSON e.g. not only class fields?

If it's definitely the rendering that is the problem you might want to consider using a LRU cache when inserting the data into WeatherLogs, essentially denormalizing the data that is being requested by the clients. Because, depending on your traffic and the amount of queries possible(although this will also influence the denormalized data) it will almost never hit the cache when it's generated on render time. This article might be a good start: http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-as-LRU-cache.html

But without understanding exactly why the rendering takes so long I wouldn't go as far as building a sophisticated cache, if JSON rendering is the problem OJ might be a solution or whatever lib is claiming to be the fastest but I have a hunch it's not the actual rendering that's the problem.

Happy o help if you have any further questions.

Comment: is there any way can response the raw results from postgreSQL, skip the rendering task ?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your detailed explaination, I hope you can give me more tips or directions about skipping rendering thanks

Comment: Sure, I'd need a little more info though. Have you looked into profiling the rendering?(ruby-prof: https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof). Also could you look into answering the first paragraph of question in my initial response? Anyway to eliminate the rendering you'd have to render them when new data gets inserted into the DB. Where and when does this happen, and what are the possible query params (The q passed into WeatherLog.result(q)) ?

Comment: Hi I added a dataflow chart to explain , try to explain it more clearly

Comment: - What are the possible query params used in the initial HTTP request?
- How does the WeatherLogs data get added to the DB?
- Is the rendering calling any other methods then just the DB fields? (Have you profiled \@weather_logs.to_s ? Is to_s/to_json a custom implementation?)
- How big is the collection in \@Weather_logs that takes ~30 seconds?

Comment: Hi I updated the post, there is a simple http request for query the weather log. The render takes longer than 30 seconds, can I skip rendering. And response query result ? maybe it's postgreSQL object

Comment: I can't help you until you give me more information. Please look at answering my questions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call Oj explicitly:

```
  def index
    begin         
      @weather_logs = WeatherLog.result(q)

      respond_to do |format|
        render json: Oj.dump(@weather_logs)
        return
      end
```

And if you want to make it implicit, try this gem by my company: https://github.com/GoodLife/rails-patch-json-encode

Comment: I'm so sorry , this can not help me speed up the bottleneck.is there any way to speedup ?or skip rendering ?

Comment: so there is no speed difference when you use Oj.dump? There should at least be some.

Comment: it will be fatser but not helps much. Can I Skip the rendering and respond the raw result from client ?